# The determinant of the sum of a positive definite matrix with a symmetric singular matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, positive-definite

I came across this problem when trying to prove the following: If you have two binary random variables $A$, $B$ that are positively correlated with probability $p$ and otherwise are uncorrelated, prove that they are correlated on average. Correlation here is defined as $P(a=0, b=0)P(a=1, b=1) - P(a=0,b=1)P(a=1,b=0)$ as per the Pearson correlation measure. Notice that this measure can be calculated directly from the joint probability matrix $\rho_{AB}$, which is a $2\times 2$ matrix with elements $[\rho_{AB}]_{i,j} = P(a = i, b= j)$. The correlation measure is just the determinant of this matrix.

In the scenario described, the joint distribution is therefore the convex sum of a positive definite matrix (the joint distribution matrix for when they are correlated, multiplied by $p$) and a symmetric singular matrix multiplied by $(1-p)$ (this is singular as $(1-p)$ of the time the two variables are uncorrelated, giving a Pearson correlation of 0, and it is symmetric as when they are correlated $P(a=i, b=j) = P(a=i)P(b=j)$.

My question is this - it is obvious from this case that when two random variables are positively correlated $p$ of the time, and uncorrelated $(1-p)$ of the time, then their probability distribution is correlated. This demands that a positive definite matrix summed with a symmetric singular matrix is a positive definite matrix, under the following constraints.

1. The matrices are positive with rows that sum to 1
2. (If needs be) the matrices are $2\times 2$ dimensional

How can I prove this? And is this a generic feature, or does the proof need to use things like the fact that the matrices rows sum to 1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is not even true for numbers: $1+(-2)=-1$.

Comment: good point. So then it needs to be under the constraints that Ive highlighted in the edited version, which pertain to the original formulation of the problem in terms of probability matrices.

Comment: Not sure how to read your constraint. Now both matrices are positive?